# How to use 3-dimensional numpy arrays with swig

Tags: arrays, numpy, swig

I'm trying to move a few functions in a python script to c to increase computation speed. I've successfully done so for a function that has several 1-dimensional arrays as input and returns a double using the numpy.i typemaps.

However, another function i want to move to c takes a 3-dimensional numpy array as an input, and returns a 1-dimensional array of doubles. I have tried the same approach as with the function before, but so far this has only resulted in segmentation faults when the function is called.

This is what I did:

the function in c is defined as (the 3d-array is "WF", the array to be returned is "charges", and "pos_x", "pos_y and "pos_z" are some 1D input-arrays):

```
void GetCharges(double* pos_x, double* pos_y, double* pos_z, double* charges, double*** WF, double resolution, double shape, int number){
...
}
```

The entries of "WF" are adressed in the code as `WF[i][j][k]`.

The SWIG interface-file looks like this:

```
/* file: GetCharges.i */
%module GetCharges
%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "GetCharges.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
import_array();
%}


%apply (double* IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double* pos_x, int number1),(double* pos_y, int number2),(double* pos_z, int number3)}
%apply (double* IN_ARRAY3, int DIM1, int DIM2, int DIM3) {(double*** WF, int dim1, int dim2, int dim3)}
%apply (double* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double* charges, int number4)}

%rename (GetCharges) GetCharges_temp;
%ignore GetCharges;
%inline %{

void GetCharges_temp(double* pos_x, int number1, double* pos_y, int number2, double* pos_z, int number3, double *charges, int number4, double*** WF, int dim1, int dim2, int dim3, double resolution, double  shape)
{
GetCharges(pos_x, pos_y, pos_z, charges, WF, resolution, shape, number1);
}
%}

%include "GetCharges.h"
```

as you can see, I tried to use the INPLACE_ARRAY for the array of the returned values.

I'm not used to c, so maybe the error is something very simple and stupid.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see how the mappings have to be applied, see numpy.i.
Herein the typemap you want to use is defined as

```
(DATA_TYPE* IN_ARRAY3, DIM_TYPE DIM1, DIM_TYPE DIM2, DIM_TYPE DIM3)
```

But you are applying it as

```
%apply (double* IN_ARRAY3, int DIM1, int DIM2, int DIM3) {(double*** WF, int dim1, int dim2, int dim3)}
```

So you put a `double*` onto a `double***`.
Although C will accept this argument your program segfaults when accessing the memory.

You need to define your internal three dimensional memory either as a single vector of type `double*` or you need an additional wrapper function which does the correct mapping either by copying it over (slow) or providing the appropriate memory addresses (fast).

Since you are already adding a temporary function, you can easily use that to create the proper memory layout for `GetCharges(...,double*** WF)` but  you need to change the function definition to

```
%apply (double* IN_ARRAY3, int DIM1, int DIM2, int DIM3) {(double* WF, int dim1, int dim2, int dim3)}
%apply (double* INPLACE_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double* charges, int number4)}
```

...

```
void GetCharges_temp(double* pos_x, int number1, double* pos_y, int number2, double* pos_z, int number3, double *charges, int number4, double* WF, int dim1, int dim2, int dim3, double resolution, double  shape)
```

**Edit**

To answer your comment, I will add here a few more lines:
Since I usually interface exisiting C code I was assuming that you have already a required memory layout. Sorry, about that.

So the real question is, how do you access the elements of `WF` in `C`? You get a `double*` with total length of `DIM1*DIM2*DIM3`. In Numpy you access an element via `WF[i][j][k]`. To do the same in `C` you need to calculate the correct offset for this element as `WF[k+DIM3*(j +DIM2*i)]` if `WF` is (C contiguous) [row major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) and `WF[i+DIM1*(j +DIM2*k)]` if `WF` is (Fortran contiguous) column major. You can check ordering in numpy by accessing `WF.flags`. Also, you can force `C` row major ordering upon `WF` in numpy by using either [numpy.ascontiguousarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ascontiguousarray.html#numpy.ascontiguousarray) or [numpy.require](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.require.html#numpy.require).

So essentially all numpy arrays of any dimension are vectors of dim `n1*...*nd`, which are accessed in the same way in `C`: by calculating the correct offset.

In row-major stored elements the fast index is the last one (here `k`) whereas in column major the fast index is the first one (here `i`). The fast index should be in the inner most loop in `C` to gain maximum speed up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I already tried to do what you are suggesting, but always encountered the following error: `GetCharges.h:3:6: note: expected ‘double ***’ but argument is of type ‘double *’`, how do I create the correct memory layout?

Comment: Well, that depends on how `double*** WF` is defined. You need to find the memory allocation routine of WF to know, how the memory layout should be. Post a new question with that code snippet, than someone might be able to answer that. The warning suggest that you missed to replace one `double*** WF` with `double* WF`. Without seeing your code it is hard to say.

Comment: WF is just a 3-dimensional numpy array, which is initialized like this: `WF = numpy.zeros([48,48,48])` and then filled with data. How do I find the memory allocation of this array?